# Flags VS Joins in DB

Tags: sql, database, join, database-design

If in a databse we have a parent table and two children tables. Is it better to use joins to get the children or add a flag to distinguish them ?

For example, the parent table is Person[Person_Name, Person_ID]. The first child table is Employee[Person_ID, Employee_ID, Department] and the other child is Customer[Person_ID, Location, Rank].

So, is it a good thing to add flag [isEmployee] or [isCustomer] to the parent table (Person) and save the effort of Joining the tables on "person_Id" ?

Another case would be with one child, for example, the parent table would be Member[Member_Name, Member_ID] and a child table GoldenMember[Member_ID, Phone_Number, EMail].

Now in this case, if I want to show the info of a specific Member, I need to do a join between tables to see whether it's a Golden Memmber or not, but if the flag "isGolden" was in the table (Member) it would save us a join?

So, which is better and why ??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A relational database is designed to perform joins.

Comment: Depends on your data volume, if you like to add a flag, would suggest add PersonType, so in future it's expandable without adding more column. For normal case you will still need to join their child table to get more info right ? like Department or Rank

Comment: First advice I'd give here is to think really hard whether you really want the exclusion rule.  Is it impossible for Employees to also be customers ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "better" unless you provide criteria for measurement of "goodness".

SQL's support for entity subtyping is inadequate.  You can hack your way around any of the shortcomings that there are, but each hack will do no more than introduce new problems of its own.

Additional "Type" columns on the top level introduce the problem of database updating becoming more complex.  Defective update procedures will corrupt the database's integrity.

Leaving out the additional "Type" columns at the top level will make the problem of formulating read queries more complex (more joins, notably).  Many people would add here "and degrade performance", but it's unlikely that you will suffer *noticeably* from this.

Choose which difficulty is the easiest to live with in your particular use case.